# $filter all mails that do not have a "categories"

Tags: node.js, sdk, microsoft-graph-api

I try to retrieve all mails that does not have a "categories" ("categories" is a collection of strings) with the Microsoft Graph Node.JS API.

I can retrieve mail that have a category "xyz" but not the other way around.

This code retrieve successfully all mails that have the "xyz" categories :

```
   .api("/users('mybox@mydomain.com')/mailfolders/inbox/messages")
   .top(10)
   .select('subject,from,receivedDateTime')
   .filter("categories/any(t:t eq 'xyz')")
   .orderby('receivedDateTime DESC')
   .get();
```

When I try :
        `.filter("categories/any(t:t ne 'xyz')")`
I receive all the mails (with or without "categories" 'xyz')

When I try : 
        `.filter("not categories/any(t:t eq 'xyz')")`
I receive an error with `{"code": "BadRequest","message":"Filter not supported."}`

When I try : 
        `.filter("categories/all(t:t ne 'xyz')")`
I receive an error with `{"code": "BadRequest","message":"Filter not supported."}`

Answer (score 2):

did you manage to solve this problem? 2 of the 3 options you tried are explainable I guess:

1. `.filter("categories/any(t:t ne 'xyz')")`
   This will return mails which have been assigned any category different from 'xyz' or which haven't been assigned any category.
2. `.filter("not categories/any(t:t eq 'xyz')")`
   I didn't manage to get the filter working with the not keyword
3. `.filter("categories/all(t:t ne 'xyz')")`
   The 'all' keyword isn't supported in the MS Graph API as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is still looking for the answer, i think i found it.

this worked for me: NOT(categories/any())

Comment: Can you please add a specific codeline and format this in the same way that the original poster did?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).